# How to stop Clion tab key behaviour

Tags: c++, settings, clion

When on a C++ line of code like the following

```
aType.aMethod(
     std::make_shared< T_1>();
^^^^^-- Press tab here 
)
```

Clion tries to move to the next parameter(i guess), but being the only parameter it goes nowhere. I want to have the tab to just insert characters(tab or space that is) and not to try to cycle the cursor among the method parameter. Is there a way to stop this alternative functionality?

I searched to no avail in

**Settings|Editor|CodeStyle|C/C++**

Thank you

Comment: Same issue here. Cannot find the way to turn this off.

Comment: Try changing the "Next parameter" and "Previous parameter" keybindings to something else than Tab.

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov it worked. If you write it as an answer i can just give you the the correct answer mark, otherwise i'll answer to myself.

Comment: @splinux it's OK, please feel free to answer yourself and accept the answer! =)

Comment: Donating rep to new users... that's true SO love <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Try changing the "Next parameter" and "Previous parameter" keybindings to something else than Tab."

– Eldar Abusalimov Jul 5 '17 at 9:02

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, i found that tab was assigned to `Next Live Template Parameter` Under : `Main Menu` | `Navigate` | `Navigate in File` (This is in the keymap section in settings, not the actual main menu). So when i generated definitions for the methods in my class and it jumped into the cpp if there were any auto generated functions with `return initializer;` as the method body it would jump to these instead of letting me indent code so i turned that off too and now i can happily implement the methods in order and fix those up when i get to them. Alternatively if you like that setting and want to keep it turned on, Hopefully knowing that you have to tidy up all instances of `return initializer;` before the tab key will indent code again is useful to you, i found it very confusing.

EDIT: i realise this wasn't part of the original question, but this is where googles top result brought me, so i hope you don't mind me adding this info here as its still related to the tab key doing weird things in CLion.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was driving me nuts and I find it insane that this is the default behaviour....